# Importing Android Sample classes into Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Good Evening,

I am trying to import the [`MatrixGrabber`](https://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/spritetext/MatrixGrabber.html) and [`MatrixStack`](https://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/spritetext/MatrixStack.html) into my android project in Eclipse. For some reason I cannot do it!

I first try to configure the build path and link over to the `com.example...` external class folder, but Eclipse still does not recognize the variable `MatrixGrabber`. When I mouseover the variable it does not give me a choice to import that library!

In the source file for the `MatrixGrabber`, the file says that it is part of the package package `com.example.android.apis.graphics.spritetext` but I get a red squiggly line under the `com.example` when I try to import that package.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please give a little more exact information... you mention: you try to configure the build path and link over to the `com.example...` external class folder....and then you say you get a red squiggly line under `com.example` - Can you be a little more specific? What exactly are you copying over, and how are you doing it? You do know you cannot just copy those two files over from the API demos and have it work?

Comment: Never mind, looks like I have to select the check mark for the answer I use... Thanks for the heads up Calvin!

Comment: TryTryAgain, So I tried not copying over anything at first. Basically I right clicked on the project and went to build path->Configure Build path. Then inside that dialog I clicked on the button "Add Class Folder" and then navigated to the "com" folder inside the SDK. Everything appeared to work because I could see the package under all the packages, but then I still start receiving the errors. A better question to be would, assume using Eclipse I start a brand new Android project. What steps are required to be able to declare a "MatrixGrabber" object?